Django SelectDateWidget default values for month and year only
I use the SelectDateWidget in my form and want to give default values for year and month, but show the empty_label (----) on day. I either get all three fields to be empty_label, or all fields showing the default date (timezone.now()).

To set value for the year and month in SelectDateWidget while leaving the empty use

my_date = form.DateField(
       widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(empty_label=("---", None,None)),
    initial=timezone.now().replace(day=1)
)

Hope this will work now.

This just overwrites the empty_label text, but still puts the default value into all three date fields.

To your edit, replace() only accept values from 1 to 31, selecting the nth day (for example October 1st). This still will not show the empty_label value.

Yes, You're right the empty-label only changes the display text, but the default value is still set. To ensure the fields are empty initially, you can remove the initial value altogether or set it to None.
